# Twilio start call forwarding after the prior call is disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twilio

I have a use case where I want to forward a call from A to C. Here if the call is already forwarded to some number i.e A to B, then I need to disable the current forwarding(i.e A to B) and then enable the new call forwarding(i.e A to C). But the new forwarding should start only if the disable call worked. I am using twilio webhook call to identify the call status. The approach I have followed is, in the method to which webhook sends response, I am checking the status of call. So when its completed, I try to find the Phone A from my apps database using call_Sid. I am storing call_Sid against the phone number that is to be forwarded. But here is the main problem.

Now when I receive status as completed for disabling I need the number to which I need to forward the call to. How should I get this new number to be passed into this method which handled twilio webhook response.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: You can pass query string parameters in your Twilio Web-hook. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

hey this issue look like previous one on [Twilio call forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319093/twilio-call-forwarding/)

someone facing issue with [twilio call forwarding](http://techloyce.com/twilio-click-to-call/) and got its solution:
It is not possible to forward calls to a Twilio number and have that number call you back if you've set up call forwarding on your phone.